# ¿como llamo las variables que tienen mis metodos de python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

estoy trabajando en una "práctica" propia basada en la creacion de un "minijuego" de blackjack en la terminal, lo que ocurre es que hice un metodo que me entrega de forma aleatoria los datos de una carta nueva **palo, numero y si es 10 de forma aleatoria elige si es J, queen, king o un 10 normal** el tema es que al ser un modulo, no se como lograr sacar las variables que tengo ingresadas en el mismo, ejemplo: si el metodo me genera un

```py
def cartaNueva(): #metodo
   numero = 5
   print(5, "of spades")
```

como logro tomar la variable "numero" y usarla en mi codigo principal, tras importar este metodo???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente debes hacer que la función retorne el valor, de ésta forma podrás asignar una variable a la referencia al objeto retornada o hacer o que quieras con ella.

Dado que en tu caso en principio retornarás una tupla (numero de la carta y su palo), puedes desempaquetarla en dos variables:

**`modulo.py`**

```
def cartaNueva():
   numero = 5       # Generado aleatoriamente
   palo = "spades"  # Generado aleatoriamente
   return numero, palo
```

**`main.py`**

```
import modulo

numero, palo = modulo.cartaNueva()

# numero será un entero en éste caso (5) y palo una cadena ("spades").
```

Ten en cuenta que una función solo puede retornar un objeto, `None` por defecto si no se ejecuta un estamento `return`. Para poder retornar más de un objeto se empaquetan en tuplas, `return numero, palo` es solo azúcar sintáctica para `return(numero, palo)`.

El desempaquetado:

```
numero, palo = (5, "spades")
```

sería similar a hacer:

```
numero = (5, "spades")[0]
palo = (5, "spades")[1]
```

Si solo quieres la cadena, similar al `print` que tienes ahora:

**`modulo.py`**

```
def cartaNueva():
   numero = 5
   palo = "spades"
   return f"{numero} of {palo}"
```

**`main.py`**

```
import modulo

carta = modulo.cartaNueva() # carta será una cadena "5 of spades"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay maneras un poco más exóticas pero el 99% de las veces utiliza `return`.

Por ejemplo:

```
def cartaNueva():
    numero = 5
    return numero

print(cartaNueva())

>>> 5
```

`return` hace exactamente lo que dice, devuelve lo que le digas a quien invoca la función; sea un numero, una cadena de texto, una lista....